# Any λ codomain liftable to `Unit`?

Tags: kotlin, subtyping

Obviously, this is rejected by the type-checker:

```
val a: Unit = 42 // Fail
```

However, this is fine:

```
val b: Unit = { 42 }() // Pass
```

I can understand that:

```
val f: ()->Any = { -> 42 } // Pass
```

Since `Int <: Any`. However, it has to be different for `Unit` (it is not a super type of `Int`). Is there some documentation explaining what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official docs cover this under [lambda expression syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax):

> If the inferred return type of the lambda is not Unit, the last (or possibly single) expression inside the lambda body is treated as the return value.

So basically, if you explicitly assign the lambda to a function type that returns `Unit` or you call it and assign its result to `Unit`, it will infer that you don't wish to return the last expression inside the lambda (which would otherwise happen by default).

Answer (score 4):

```
val b: Unit = { 42 }()
```

Since you explicitly specify the variable type of `b` to be `Unit`, the lambda will not actually `return 42`. On the other hand, if you let the compiler infer the function type or specify it appropriately, *the last lambda statement is made the result*, which is of type `Int` in this case.

Both of the following are possible:

```
val b1: () -> Unit = { 42 }
val b2: () -> Int = { 42 }
```

As well as these (directly invoke the lambda):

```
val a1: Unit = { 42 }() 
val a2: Int = { 42 }()
```

The documentation can be found [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax).

> A lambda expression is always surrounded by curly braces, parameter declarations in the full syntactic form go inside curly braces and have optional type annotations, the body goes after an -> sign. *If the inferred return type of the lambda is not `Unit`, the last (or possibly single) expression inside the lambda body is treated as the return value.*